# Selenium IDE - which webmailer do you prefer for testing?

Tags: selenium

Dear Selenium IDE Friends.

I test my webapplication via Firefox-Plugin Selenium IDE. I have to test: sending a newsletter and verify the newsletter-text. Selenium IDE cant´t break out of the browser to move to my outlook, so i have to use a webmailer. Some webmailer like 1und1 or freenet have frames in the layout. Selenium IDE doesn´t select elements in frames, even not by function "selectFrame".

MY Question: Which Webmailer has no frames and supports testing with Selenium IDE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option: Let your developers build you some in-house web mail suitable for such testing.

If thats not an option, try [10minutemail](http://10minutemail.com/)

1. You get new inbox every time (new e-mail address)
2. No frames
3. Selenium IDE should be able to read it

Of course. As long as you are about to use 3rd party app for your testing, consider donating some money to them ;)